# How To Implement Rest Full Web Service with Auth Token using Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, restful-authentication

I am trying to design an API Manager with RESTful webservice. In Spring's new release, we can combine everything in Java code without using `web.xml` nor `securityconfig.xml`. 
According to Authtoken concept, API manager should have authtoken and refresh token for user authentication.
Please, can anyone give me sample source code or guidance how to implement RESTfull webservice with Spring Security.

1. I need to know how all configurations are implement in Java code.
2. it should have Authtoken concept also.

This Tutorial Say correct way to do this.

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html

But Spring Configuration are in Spring.xml file.

I need to put them in to Java level also.

Comment: What do you mean with `Authtoken concept`? Do you mean [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/)?

Comment: I mean Normally, When we connect to the API, they give to token and refresh token for client. When token time is expired, we can get new token by giving refresh token. I need to how it is achieve in Spring Security. :)

Comment: Maybe [Spring Security OAuth2 samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/2.0.7.RELEASE/samples/oauth2) can help you. They have samples for both sides client and server.

Comment: Thanx ksokol ,  But They have Spring MVC application. In my API manager Not View part. In my service return only JSON objects. In this examples, Security part was done by login.jsp page. In my application has no View (no html pages) part :(.

Answer (score 2):

The people at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com) have a quite a straightforward solution for achieving Oauth. Please take a look at [Using Stormpath for API Authentication](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/).

As a summary, your solution will look like this:

1. You will use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs.
2. When the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials securely to your backend-end through its REST API.

   2.1. By the way, Stormpath greatly enhances all the possibilities here. Instead of having your own login page, you can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/), or you can also delegate it to the [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html). Stormpath also supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login.
3. Your backend will then try to authenticate the user against the Stormpath Backend and will return an `access token` as a result:

   ```
   /** This code will throw an Exception if the authentication fails */
   public void postOAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       //Getting the authentication result
       AccessTokenResult result = (AccessTokenResult) application.authenticateApiRequest(request);

       //Here you can get all the user data stored in Stormpath
       Account account = accessTokenResult.getAccount();

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
       response.setContentType("application/json");

       //Return the Access Token
       response.getWriter().print(token.toJson());
       response.getWriter().flush();
   }
   ```
4. Then, for every authenticated request, your backend will do:

   ```
   /** This is your protected API */
   public void sayHello(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       OauthAuthenticationResult result = (OauthAuthenticationResult) application.authenticateOauthRequest(request).execute();

       System.out.println(result.getApiKey());
       System.out.println(result.getAccount());

       //At this point the authorization was successful, you can now allow the actual operation to be executed
       doSayHello();
   }
   ```

All this will not need any special Spring Security configuration, this is plain Java code that you can run in any framework.

Please take a look [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens) for more information.

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.